# set default imageorient for TCEFORM

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I want to set the default imageorient of a TCEFORM.
Standard value is 17 but I want to use 18.

So I tried like mentioned here https://forge.typo3.org/issues/16676 
this two methods in my PageTsConfig.ts:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.imageorient.default = 18
TCAdefaults.tt_content.imageorient = 18
```

and

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.elements.image.tt_content_defValues.imageorient = 18
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.elements.textpic.tt_content_defValues.imageorient = 18
```

but neither the one nor the other is working.

Any hints how I can achieve this?

Comment: as said in the forge ticket: you can not achieve it until the patch is installed.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ but it is marked as resolved and done 6 months ago

Comment: 'resolved' normaly means: merged to master.  and on https://review.typo3.org/#/c/47266/ there is no mention of 7.6, only 8.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my cas it was

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.elements.textmedia.tt_content_defValues.imageorient = 18
```

instaed of

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.elements.textpic.tt_content_defValues.imageorient = 18
```

Comment: That is likely because you are using css_styled_content (the "old" way of rendering content) instead of fluid_styled_content (the "new" approach).